# Mask an Image over Video in Android

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, android-ffmpeg, image-masking

[image]

See the Example image shown above. Y is a video having chrome key color inside it(here RED Color). X is an image to be clipped on video chrome key and Output is shown in the image.
Now the problem is, the chrome key (RED Color part) is moving a bit while playing so, is there any way to clip and mask an image on video directly?

Right now I'm using

1. Platform: Android
2. Library: FFmpeg
3. File Types: Video(mp4) and Image(png)

Comment: which type of moving like rotating, left to right moving or any thing else?

Comment: @KiranManiya have you any solution for this now?

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel I solved by Image Frame Composition. As given below.
1. Get video Frame as Bitmap
2. Use Clipping Mask to Clip another Image on Red Area Of Video Frame.
3. Render the Video Using New Images Masked with Image.

Comment: @KiranManiya I tried with same. but didn't found success in output. can you share ffmpeg command here for clipping image inside red area??